# German special characters Ää, Öö, Üü, ß are displaying incorrectly in LiveLink or opentext

Tags: c#, livelink

I have Document and folder in Live link containing German special characters Ää, Öö, Üü, ß. I extracted the document and folder name using following code of LiveLink API server version 9.2.0.0 and client version API version of LiveLink 9.5.0.0.

```
string encodedName = LLValueUtil.GetValue(mainLLObj, "Name").TrimEnd('.');
int charIndex = 0;

while (Array.IndexOf(WhitespaceChars, encodedName[charIndex]) >= 0) {
    string replacement = System.Xml.XmlConvert.EncodeName(encodedName[charIndex].ToString());
    encodedName = encodedName.Substring(0, charIndex) + replacement + encodedName.Substring(charIndex + 1);
    charIndex += replacement.Length;
}

charIndex = encodedName.Length - 1;
// Replaces trailing WhitespaceChars

while (Array.IndexOf(WhitespaceChars, encodedName[charIndex]) >= 0) {
    string replacement = System.Xml.XmlConvert.EncodeName(encodedName[charIndex].ToString());
    string lastPart = encodedName.Substring(charIndex + 1);
    encodedName = encodedName.Substring(0, charIndex) + replacement + lastPart;
    charIndex = encodedName.Length - replacement.Length - lastPart.Length - 1;
}

string documentName = encodedName; // give fine File name
```

this code works fine in Livelink sever API version 9.5.0.0. but does not work in LiveLink API server version 9.7.1. Could you help me fixing for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin panel of server Livelink/livelink.exe?func=admin.sysvars and set Character Set: UTF-8 and code section change as follow

```
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value); 
    var retValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```